# I can't format my chapter titles

Tags: titlesec

I am trying to format the chaptertitles in my dissertation, but titlesec doesn't seem to work...

```
    \documentclass[12p]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ő}{\H{o}}
\newunicodechar{ű}{\H{u}}
\PassOptionsToPackage{defaults=hu-min}{magyar.ldf}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{magyar}{,,}{''}{>>}{<<} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\normalfont\chapfnt\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{}

\begin{document}
\title{TITLE OF MY DISSERTATION}
\author{My name}

\maketitle

\include{chap1}

\end{document}
```

THe chap1 file:

```
\chapter{Very very long chapter title to appear in multiple line in the begining of the chapter}
```

And my titles look like this:
[image]

Basically, I would want my chapter title to begin in the same line as the label, 12 point, times new roman, standard stuff, but for some reason, this code doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: As is your code is not usable (removing \chapfn I do not notice anything wrong). You should provide an minimal working example. See this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Sorry, provided the whole code now.

Comment: Thanks, while this solved the current program, it generated a lot more... but thanks anyway :)